# Dynamically set the select-options while loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I need to dynamically set the select options based on the one value which is getting from the controller while loading the page.

```
<script>
validate selectOptions();

function selectOptions(){
var healthWorkerQuestions1 = "${healthWorkerQuestions}";
if(healthWorkerQuestions1 == "6" || healthWorkerQuestions1 == "7" || healthWorkerQuestions1 == "8"){
                 alert("six to eight"); 
                 $('#questionOptions').empty();
                 var sel = document.getElementById('questionOptions');
                  for(var i = 0; i < drinker.length; i++) {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.innerHTML = drinker[i];
                    opt.value = drinker[i];
                    $('questionOptions').append(opt).selectmenu('refresh');
                    //sel.appendChild(opt).selectmenu('refresh');
                   }             
        }

}
</script>
```

Here the loop is executing and able to see the alert box. And the select box options are not updating in the select box.  I tried in two ways as follows,

```
$('questionOptions').append(opt).selectmenu('refresh');
sel.appendChild(opt).selectmenu('refresh');
```

But the options are not updating while loading the page.

The code for select box is:

```
<select name="questionOptions" id="questionOptions">
<option>Select</option>
</select>
```

After loading the page I am able to see only select option but not the dynamically appended values. How can I update the select option on page loading.

Any suggestions please..

Comment: use $('#questionOptions').append(opt).selectmenu('refresh'); rather $('questionOptions').append(opt).selectmenu('refresh');

Comment: Sorry, I am using  $('#questionOptions').append(opt).selectmenu('refresh'); typo mistake while writing the question. Still the options are not updating in the list. Any other solutions please

Comment: I think append return the appended element but selectmenu should be  called on select so change the code to  
for ... { 
sel.appendChild(opt);
}
$('questionOptions').selectmenu('refresh');

Comment: I tried your suggestion. still the select box options are not updating. How can I do the same. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is looks fine. To update the select option call the method form jQuery document ready function as mentioned below,

```
<script>
$(function(){
selectOptions();
});

function selectOptions(){
// Your code here....
}
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.